# Text wrapping is breaking words in odd way, distorting text

Tags: google-sheets

I'm developing a series of quotes for a prospective client and there's a "NOTES" column where I explain the costs. The explanations are three to four sentences so I turned on the text wrap function. The problem is text wrap is breaking up words strangely.

[image: WA97851 question example]

Is there any way to remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are in `justify` text mode, try to change it to `align left` mode.